# How to create div based on percentage height and width?

Tags: html, css

Give me idea to create height and width of div based on percentage.

Here in this i have created by table. the same thing i want to create with div.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%" height="80%">
<colgroup>
   <col width="80%" />
   <col width="20%" />
</colgroup>
<tr>
  <td style="background-color: yellow;">abc</td>
  <td style="background-color: red;">cde</td>
</tr>
```

above both td should be scrollable. should not expand its size with content. can anybody create example demo for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is, that your `div`'s needs to be scrollable, so I would recommened to use an absolute position:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto
}


.left {
    width: 80%;
    left: 0;
    background: red
}


.right {
    width: 20%;
    left: 80%;
    background: yellow
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/eZerH/

**Update**

To prevent absolute positioning, try this float-based layout:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/eZerH/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/itz2k13/64WAW/6/

```
.inner-box-80{
  width: 80%; 
  float: left;
  background-color: red;    
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inner-box-20{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pls try the css3 flexbox module.

```
html,body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
body {
  display: -moz-box; /*Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers. */
  display: -webkit-box;/* Firefox (buggy) */
  display: -ms-flexbox; /*IE 10*/
  display: -webkit-flex;/*Chrome 21+ */
  display: flex;/*Opera 12.1, Firefox 22+ */

  -moz-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-box-algin: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.main {
  background: green;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto
}
.sidebar {
  background: orange;
  width: 20%;
}
```

pls view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/ipCeA).